# OSX - Get a selector with list of systems fonts

Tags: macos, fonts, system, selector

In my new app, I need the user to be able to click a selector, and pick any of their system fonts. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+[UIFont familyNames]` returns an array of names of installed fonts.

**Edit:** Oops, I was in iOS mode. Here's the Mac OS version:

`[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableFontFamilies]`

Comment: `[UIFont familyNames]` won't work with OSX though, it's supposed to be `NSFont`.